# Is this an expected directory under /run/user/1000?

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu

I have a directory under /run/user/1000 that looks like this from an ls -al.

```
  d?????????  ? ?    ?      ?            ? doc
```

Is this normal, or an error of some sort?

Answer (score 3):

This is normal, and results from the permissions on the directory /run/user/1000.
You need read permission on a directory in order to read the *contents* of the directory (ie do an `ls`). However, you need execute permission in order to `stat` any file inside the directory. `ls -l` uses `stat` behind the scenes to get information about a file, so if you don't have execute permissions on the folder, you can see the files inside, but not any information about them.

In short, this is a normal file with a name and permissions that are not all question marks, but you can't see the information because you don't have execute permissions on the folder.

Comment: your answer make sense and satisfies my curiosity.

Comment: you can upvote my answer if it helped you, and mark it as "accepted" in a day or so if it is the best answer by then.